# Photoelectric effect Experiment - What's the voltage bias of the set up?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, photoelectric-effect

[image]
What's the bias of the setup? Forward / Reverse?

I'm doing a photoelectric effect experiment.The experimental setup involves a photocell, which has an emitter (cathode) Potassium and a collector(anode) made of Pt. I did some measurements without the external voltage source, I got a positive current response. And When I switched the large reverse bias on, the current became negative, which I think the battery is applying a retarding potential to the electrons, in other words, stopping the electrons to jump to the collector plate, overall current flows in opposite direction.

Therefore, I think the picture below is showing a voltage applying a forward bias, is my reasoning correct?

Comment: If you are getting a reverse current, then you are either generating charges at the collector (which is perfectly possible) or you have a leakage current path in your experiment (which is also perfectly possible). Turn the light source off (and maybe the lights in the room!). Does the current go away? If it does, there is some secondary source of photoelectrons at play, if it doesn't, then you have a leakage path which distorts all of your results. The leakage without any light is something the careful experimental physicist will measure anyway as part of error analysis.

Comment: @CuriousOne Hi CuriousOne, Thanks for your reply. If I get a reverse current, what charges am I generating at the collector? Positive/Negative charge?

Comment: @CuriousOne Also, Do you know what voltage bias is being apply in the setup? Forward/Reverse ? Please provide explanation Thanks!

Comment: It's always negative electrons that are flowing. What kind of bias one uses depends on the experiment. Are you trying to measure the total generated charge? Then it's a forward bias. Are you trying to measure the energy of the electrons? That would be a reverse bias. If you are seeing the current change sign, then electrons are flowing from the collector to the emitter, which shouldn't happen, but may. In that case you have to find out if it's a leakage current or a reverse photo current (i.e. emitter and collector have "changed place"). Good luck!

Comment: @CuriousOne In this experiment, the emitter is acting as a cathode (electron emitter) (shorter mark on the left , longer mark on the right) and the anode as an electron collector. The question I have been asking is that, is this picture showing the forward bias?